# Adjacent Repeated Substrings of Arbitrary Length

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm

My buddy was recently asked this interview question and it has me stumped!  The question asked him to write a function that would return true if a string had repeated substrings inside of it that were adjacent to each other.

For example, if given:

```
 String first = "ABCxyABC"; //This string would return false because both "ABC" are not next to each other

 String second = "ABCzzCDE"; //This string would return true because both "z" are next to each other

 String third = "12341234zAE"; // This string returns true as well, as "1234" is repeated and back-to-back
```

I was thinking that you could use some type of regular expression magic in Java, but that is as far as I could get.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is quite easy with regex. Simply try to `find` regex like `(.+)\1`
(`\1` is [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) representing match from group 1).

DEMO:

```
String first  = "ABCxyABC"; 
String second = "ABCzzCDE"; 
String third  = "12341234zAE";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\1");

System.out.println(p.matcher(first).find());  //false
System.out.println(p.matcher(second).find()); //true
System.out.println(p.matcher(third).find());  //true
```

Comment: I'm never sure with "regex" that do backtracking, but isn't that exponential in the worst case compared to the naive loop which runs in O(n^2)?

Comment: @Voo When I tested it on 300 length no-repetition string, or 600 length string (which repeats first 300 length string) it worked fine without any delays. I didn't calculate complexity of this regex but I suspect that complexity of `\1` should be O(1) since it already knows what is inside first group so it can try to simply check if string with same length after it is equal (without testing any shorter ones strings). So we are left with complexity of `.*` which is probably O(N^2) since we are simply testing combinations like (for "abc") "abc" "ab" "a" "bc" "b" "c" (but I may be wrong)